# What is the Rebel equivelant of the AT-ST?

Tags: xbox-one, star-wars-battlefront

In Supremacy, Both sides get different pickups, but for vehicles, the Rebels get the Airspeeder, the X-Wing, and the A-Wing. This gives them an undisputable advantage in the skies most of the time, as the A-Wing is usually the superior starship, and the X-Wing can help support. This said, The Airspeeder is kind of useless, it moves to fast to be super easy to gun troops down with, and is easily taken out by Ties. The Empire gets The Tie Fighter, which is about equal with the X-Wing, and the Tie Interceptor, which is usually a bit better than the X-Wing, and then they get the AT-ST, which is like a super soldier with infinite impact grenades and homing missiles. The only drawback is it's size, which makes it a huge target on the battlefield. Is the weak and almost useless Airspeeder supposed to balance out the incredible AT-ST? Or is the counterpart the A-Wing? Or the X-Wing?

Comment: You're thinking of AT-AT's, the giant ones that look like turtles with really long legs, they were taken down by the tow cables on hoth. The AT-ST's are the ones from endor, with only two legs, and a lot smaller. All terrain armored transport, and all terrain scout transport.

Comment: @RossRidge No, in one of the game modes you can get the AT-AT's down after you've activated and defended two uplinks, bomb the walkers with Y-Wings, and then successfully trip a walker with the tow cable, which is difficult. Sadly, it doesn't work on AT-ST's, which are much more common.

Comment: Is this referring to the 2015 Battlefield reboot?